# How can I toggle/animate a <div> by hovering on a <a> S

Tags: html, css, animation

So. I have an  object. If i hover it i want to toggle an animation or just a css change of the div underneath.

**I only want to use HTML & CSS** no Javascript or something.

You can find the structure in the "code" section.

Thank you for your help :)

```
<body>
 <div>
  <a ← THIS IS THE OVER OBJECT>
  <div ← THIS IS THE DIV I WANNA ANIMATE>
   stuff
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the adjacent sibling selector (note that the `div` must immediately follow the `a` in this case):

```css
a:hover + div { background: blue } /* this is all that really matters */
```

```html
<a href='#'>HOVER ME</a>
<div>I AM A DIV</div>
```

If there's another element between the `a` and the `div`, but they're still siblings, you need to use `~` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add a closing tag for your anchor element. After that, you can set the innermost div to animate when you hover on the anchor tag by doing:

```
    a:hover div{
      //Animation code here
    }
```